# Sharepoint Online scripting similar to Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, sharepoint-online

For several years we've had a Google Site setup on a non-profit G-Suite domain. This site is used once a year for a conference we hold with about 200 deleagates. The site is used by delegates for some simple stuff like reading documents, but there is a much more complex part of it too.

I've used Google apps script to write a system where users can do voting, speaker queueing, elections, and a daily checkin/rollcall.  How it looks to users is they goto a page, and they see a "Vote Yes", "Vote No", and "Abstain" button. These are embedded Google apps script applets on the Google site page.  Similar for the speaker queue and other functions.

On the backend, when a user clicks "Yes" or "No", the script submits a Google form on their behalf, with that answer. The form is tied to a Google sheet. Originally we had it directly append a line to a google sheet, but found with 200 people voting at the same time, we ran into performance issues and limitations with Google sheets.

The script then does stuff like de-deuplicate the results (incase someone voted multiple times), tabulates the results, and displays the results. This is all done on another page on the site that the officers running the conference can see.

For speaker queue, users basically click a button to say "I want to speak", and their names get added to a google sheet. The officers running the conference then call them up when it's their turn to speak.  Users can also click a button to see where they are in the queue, and they'll get a response on the page like "You are currently number 3 of 27 users in the queue". They can also click a different button to remove themselves from the queue.

With that all explained, we're looking at potentially switching away from Google Sites, and considering Microsoft Sharepoint Online.  The reason for this is we're using "old" Google sites, which Google has said will be shutdown at some point. "New" google sites currently does not support any scripting or API's at all, so it's impossible to redo our site in that system currently. They say API's are coming, but no details on what will and won't be available.

We have access to a free non-profits domain on Office365 (E1 tier) which gives us sharepoint online, active directory online, and $5k for free Azure credits.

So I'm asking you all here if there is some similar system available with O365/Sharepoint online. I'd want to change where all the data is stored to an SQL database, as storing stuff in sheets isn't ideal from any viewpoint, it's just the best option we had at the time.  Ideally, the code for this would all live in the cloud like it does with Google. If I have to write code in Visual studio and upload it then I'm OK with that, but for maintenance purposes it would be really nice to have it all stored in the cloud and not need to install a thick app to work on it.

Basically we need the ability for users to login to a sharepoint site with their o365 account (we issue them the account), be able to interact with the site to send and receive data from SQL (which is running in Azure on same domain).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It seems much more complex on the MS side, with way more potential methods for doing it (Graph, Sharepoint Addons, etc).

A couple photos:
[image: Voting]
[image: SpeakerQueue]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide a no coding solution here. If we want to code, then we can use SharePoint Add-in to do almost everything, such as collect user input and display data.

> I've used Google apps script to write a system where users can do voting, speaker queueing, elections, and a daily checkin/rollcall. How it looks to users is they goto a page, and they see a "Vote Yes", "Vote No", and "Abstain" button. These are embedded Google apps script applets on the Google site page. Similar for the speaker queue and other functions.
>
> On the backend, when a user clicks "Yes" or "No", the script submits a Google form on their behalf, with that answer. The form is tied to a Google sheet. Originally we had it directly append a line to a google sheet, but found with 200 people voting at the same time, we ran into performance issues and limitations with Google sheets.

I think we can create a Microsoft Form or Microsoft PowerApps to get user response. And then Store the data to a SharePoint list.

> The script then does stuff like de-deuplicate the results (incase someone voted multiple times), tabulates the results, and displays the results. This is all done on another page on the site that the officers running the conference can see.

We can use Microsoft Flow to process the data, such as remove duplicated data. On the other hand, we can display results in PowerApps.

> For speaker queue, users basically click a button to say "I want to speak", and their names get added to a google sheet. The officers running the conference then call them up when it's their turn to speak. Users can also click a button to see where they are in the queue, and they'll get a response on the page like "You are currently number 3 of 27 users in the queue". They can also click a different button to remove themselves from the queue.

We can do it in PowerApps.